# how to remove all old versions and dependencies in azure-cli to COMPLETELY START FRESH

Tags: python, azure, azure-cli

So i'm using azure-cli at the moment and it refuses to work with az interactive.

I'm not sure how to accomplish this correctly/completely however;

I want to *REMOVE EVERYTHING* and **COMPLETELY** re-install **FRESH**.

How can I get this done so azure-cli will hopefully decide to work correctly again?

Answer (score 0):

Just run it from a Docker container.  That way each time you pull it's fresh as a daisy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/run-azure-cli-docker

### Windows

You uninstall the Azure CLI from the Windows "Apps and Features" list. To uninstall:
[image: Uninstall Instructions]

Remove its data from `C:\Users\<username>\.azure\msal_token_cache.bin` or `C:\Users\<username>\.azure\msal_token_cache.json`.

### Linux

Uninstall using the package manager of choice then `rm -rf ~/.azure`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-linux?pivots=apt#uninstall